# Why are jqueryUI button and buttonset positioned differently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a lot of buttons which should be displayed below each other. In some lines, there should be only one button, whereas other lines should contain two buttons with a jQuery UI buttonset.

Here is a sample code:

```js
$( "button" ).button();
$( ".split" ).buttonset();
```

```css
div {
    width: 280px;
    text-align: center;
}

div button {
    width: 70%;
}

button.splitleft {
    width: 55%;
}

button.splitright {
    width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="regular">
    <button type="button">Click me!</button>
</div>
<div class="split">
    <button type="button" class="splitleft">Split button</button>
    <button type="button" class="splitright">B</button>
</div>
```

The result is unfortunately not aligned correctly. Also, the buttonset in total has a different width than the button above it.

Why is this the case? Why are jQuery UI buttons and buttonsets formatted differently? Is there a way to make them the same width without having to fiddle with pixel values for margins and the like?

Comment: Because they have margins.

Comment: @Nit Well, yes, that is the technical reason. But why did the developers choose these different formattings, making two in my eyes very similar concepts somewhat incompatible with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unset horizontal margins on buttons so that the center is calculated correctly. Also remove the "space" between the two buttons:

```js
$("button").button();
$(".split").buttonset();
```

```css
@import url(https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css);

div {
  width: 280px;
  text-align: center;
}
.regular .ui-button {
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 70%;
}
.split .splitleft {
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 55%;
  border-right-width: 0;
}
.split .splitright {
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="regular">
  <button type="button">Click me!</button>
</div>
<div class="split">
  <button type="button" class="splitleft">Split button</button><!--
  --><button type="button" class="splitright">B</button>
</div>
```

Comment: A minor downside to this approach is that the border between the buttons is now twice as thick.

Comment: Remove the right border from first button. The missing right-border becomes more obvious on hover, but you have the same problem in your original example. I would rather live with the double border.